# C# time format fill-up

Tags: c#

In C#, I made a textbox that accept only numbers, but I want to make a code to accept a time in the following format:  "____:____:____" so that when the user writes part of it, it completes the missing with zeros;
Example:
The user writes: "_2:12:_3" it should complete it as "02:12:03".

Does anybody have this code?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want, but [Walkthrough: Working with the MaskedTextBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az(v=vs.100).aspx) may be of interest to you.

Comment: It won't work in all cases.  If somebody pastes a string in the box the validation will be skipped.  Question been asked a lot of times in the past.  It is better to use a DataTimePicker.

Comment: Is the Question about WinForms, WPF or something different?

Comment: You need to change your regex on that textbox (assuming you are using one) to allow the use of the colon (:), or use a MaskedTextBox that has this already set up for the user.   Then, take the entire string, use String.Split(':') to get an array of three strings, String.Length to ensure you have two characters in each string, and use string concatenation to append a 0 to the beginning of any value that has only one character.    After that, set the .Text value of the control to be each string in the array separated by a ':'.

Comment: it's Win forms, I used Masked text box to give me the format of 00:00:00,

Comment: I want the code to start with "HOURS" when he puts "2", the code displays it "02" and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best would be to use the Replace() function in C# as follow:

```
string x = "this is an example of a string with a _ character";

string z = x.Replace('_', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(YourTextBox.Text);
            if (value<10)
            {
                YourTextBox.Text = "0" + value;
            }
        }
```

and Ofcourse you can add other logic like if the user enters more than 60 for the minutes textbox the text should be replaced with an empty string

Comment: Thank you all I've done it;

Comment: ` string str = x.Text;
                    int i = 0;
                    string ss = "";
                    foreach (string s in new List<string>(str.Split(':')))
                    {
                        i = int.Parse(s);
                        if (int.Parse(s) < 10)
                        {
                            ss += '0' + System.Convert.ToString(i);
                        }
                        else ss += System.Convert.ToString(s);
                    }
                    i = int.Parse(ss);
                    x.Text = i.ToString("D6"); `